# Magento Checkout Conversion Back to Base Currency not Working

Tags: magento, currency, checkout

After installing a magento connect theme I am having an issue on checkout whereby; whichever total is being displayed in a converted currency (not base), is not being converted back into base on final checkout/place order. Any ideas where the code is that handles this final conversion? I have contacted the extension vendor though am awaiting a reply. Thank you

```
Subtotal    Rs6,723.03

Processing Fee  Rs672.30

Grand Total Rs7,395.34

Your credit card will be charged for    £7,395.34
```

Screenshot here (less than 10 rep so can't embed! only posted once before which resulted in a triumph!)

[image]

EDIT -----

Hi thanks for the suggestion, however the currency rates are set and the correct values for each are confirmed. When using a default magento install (sample data) the problem is not occurring, which means it’s isolated to the extension I’m using.

I have had a dig about in the theme files and have isolated the currency functions to be occurring in the the files found in the following path (theme files)

app\code\local\ *extension vendor* \ *extension name*

Within this folder there are various files which may be pertaining to currency inluding:

CartController.php

Order.php

Price.php

Total.php

I am almost certain that it’s going to be a line of code within one of these files, or those within the specified folder that’s causing the issue. I am hoping someone is able to tell me where this final conversion is happening and in what file. There are equivalents of these files in the core magento folder and having this theme installed tells the website to use the third-party variants of the core/default magento file. If someone knows which file it is, I can post the code for that file to have a look at or perhaps if I knew which file I could debug myself.

Thanks again!

Comment: Is it just the symbol that is wrong?

Comment: No, the base currency is set to GBP. In the above example the user selected display currency is INR. The conversion rates are set correctly on backend so should be converting to base currency.

Comment: change your store in the top left dropdown and make sure the currency is set properly for your store.

Comment: See [Edit "Your credit card will be charged for" on onepage checkout to show desired currency](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/2914)